# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to manually set all the properties in my SPring Boot application,  as I will be using a different DataSource eventually for regular JDBC stuff.  But here is my code:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource getJpaDatasource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(hibernateConfiguration.getDriverClassName());
    dataSource.setUrl(hibernateConfiguration.getDatabaseUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(hibernateConfiguration.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(hibernateConfiguration.getPassword());
    return dataSource;
}
```

Now I am using legacy code and need to create an entity factory,  and I would like to use Hikari as a connection pool.  here is the code for that:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getJpaDatasource());
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    Map<String, String> hibernateProperties = new HashMap<>();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect",hibernateConfiguration.getProperties().get("hibernate.dialect"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql",hibernateConfiguration.getProperties().get("show-sql"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.format-sql",hibernateConfiguration.getProperties().get("format-sql"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings",hibernateConfiguration.getProperties().get("id.new_generator_mappings"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",hibernateConfiguration.getProperties().get("ejb.naming_strategy"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle",hibernateConfiguration.getConnectionPool().get("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", hibernateConfiguration.getConnectionPool().get("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", hibernateConfiguration.getConnectionPool().get("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.provider_class",hibernateConfiguration.getConnectionPool().get("hibernate.connection.provider_class"));

    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProperties);
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    EntityManagerFactory ef = (EntityManagerFactory)localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    return ef;
}
```

Now nothing is returning null or anything,  I just get this error:

```
 nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

**EDIT**
To get all the obvious ones out of the way:

1. Yes,  I can connect to the DB via mysqlWorkbench
2. the username and password are correct.
3. I have tired without the Connection Pool.
4. There is no error being thrown until the first call of the db.  ie "select * from users"

This is what I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

This seems like and easy one,  but I can't figure this one out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When manually overriding things through Spring,  it's important to remember that you have to override everything.  What I forgot was the the TransactionManager. This is all it took:

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = this.getEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    EntityManagerFactory ef = (EntityManagerFactory)localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(ef);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

I don't know if the connection pooling is working and all,  but I am able to retrieve data from the database.